# my tor connection timed out?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, help

[image] when I tried to close it I couldn't it looks like it froze or something, do I have to update my mac??

its not opening, I fixed my timezone (I use a mac OS X version 10.9)

here's the log:

```
8/13/17, 2:36:57.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/13/17, 2:36:57.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/13/17, 2:38:16.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Operation timed out; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 64E99CB34C595A02A3165484BD1215E7389322C6 at 195.154.122.54:443) 
8/13/17, 2:38:16.600 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
8/13/17, 2:38:16.600 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/13/17, 2:38:53.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/13/17, 2:38:53.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/13/17, 2:38:53.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/13/17, 2:38:53.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: If that's a bridge you're trying to use there, it no longer exists.